# How to decrypt data with CryptoJS, which is encrypted by Crypto library?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I used Crypto library on client side, and since it's deprecated I'm trying to move to CryptoJS.

I have data that was encrypted (with Crypto) by this code:

```
export function encrypt(toEncrypt, password) {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', password);
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}
```

How do I decrypt the output data of this code with CryptoJS?

Comment: Crypto is not deprecated, but `.createCipher()` is, and as the developers recommend you should use `.createCipheriv()` instead. Anyway, the problem here is that you're using CTR without providing an iv/nonce. In order to decrypt that data you'll have to find the default iv/nonce used by `.createCipher()`.

Comment: [`createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) derives the key and IV from the password by hashing it with MD5. You just need to reproduce those steps (if you want full compatibility) and migrate to `createCipheriv()`. But I'd suggest to implement a stronger key derivation and a random IV. Don't use CryptoJS, it's meant for use in a browser where there is no native crypto support.

Comment: I'm working on browser, and the deprecated crypto library I mentioned is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto not the built-in crypto in NodeJS